# SQL: staging table to table with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I got a problem where I can't insert data from one table to the other using the foreign key of 3rh table. Whilst keeping the data unique.

[image: SQL diagram]

First I populate my [Fouten] table from a staging table. This query filter duplicates and stores the remaining rows, going from about 144.000 rows to 66.580 rows. This works perfectly and as it's supposed to -

```
INSERT INTO [TestDatabase].[dbo].Fouten (FoutId, Datum, Time, FoutCode,Omschrijving,TreinId, Module)
SELECT st.FoutId, st.Datum, st.Time, st.FoutCode, st.Omschrijving, st.TreinId, st.Module
FROM ( 
     SELECT FoutId, 
            Datum, 
            Time, 
            FoutCode,
            Omschrijving,
            TreinId,
            Module,
            row_number() over (partition by TreinId, Datum, Time, FoutCode order by TreinId, Datum, Time, FoutCode) as rn
     FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].foutenTemp ) as st
WHERE st.rn = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].Fouten t2
                WHERE t2.TreinId = st.TreinId 
                  AND t2.Datum = st.Datum
                  AND t2.Time = st.Time
                  AND t2.FoutCode = st.FoutCode)
```

Output:

```
[Fouten]
FoutId  Datum   Time            FoutCode    Omschrijving        Module          TreinId
4   2009-11-29  08:59:10.070    01-00-26    Overgang AC naar DC ACTRL1_A9120110 1 
5   2009-11-29  21:10:35.612    01-00-27    Overgang DC naar AC ACTRL1_A9120110 1 
6   2009-11-30  12:29:56.638    01-00-26    Overgang AC naar DC ACTRL1_A9120110 1 
10  2009-12-01  06:17:57.048    01-00-26    Overgang AC naar DC ACTRL1_A9120110 1 
15  2009-12-01  05:34:06.779    06-00-46    Def. of incoh. richtwaarde voor blending    ACTRL1_A9120110 1
```

The FoutId's missing inbetween are the duplicate ones that got removed.

I now got a second staging table containing data about the FoutId's named ExtraInfo, but these still contain duplicates. What I'm trying to do is to insert all records into the table containing restrictions based on a match on the Fout tables FoutId column and so filtering out the duplicate records. But within the table ExtraInfo there can't be a duplicate record for FoutId combined with the Value

So for example:

```
[ExtraInfo]
FoutId  Value
3   etat_x_convoi_ok = 0x01 '' 
3   old_mode_ac_dc = 0 
3   ICO_m_a_pmcf = 0 
3   APP_mode_ac_dc = 0x01 '' 
4   etat_x_convoi_ok = 0x01 '' 
4   old_mode_ac_dc = 16777216 
4   old_mode_ac_dc = 16777216 
4   ICO_m_a_pmcf = 0 
4   APP_mode_ac_dc = 0x00 '
4   APP_mode_ac_dc = 0x00 '
```

Should become:

```
[ExtraInfo]
FoutId  Value
4   etat_x_convoi_ok = 0x01 '' 
4   old_mode_ac_dc = 16777216 
4   ICO_m_a_pmcf = 0 
4   APP_mode_ac_dc = 0x00 '
```

Because the FoutId has to exist in the [Fouten] table the FoutId not containing 4 should be removed, whilst also removing any duplicate records of 4 combined with the value.

I have tried altering the first expression, because it allows for distinct rows where u can choose which columns count. This wasn't such great of a success.

```
INSERT INTO [TestDatabase].[dbo].ExtraInfo (FoutId, Value)
SELECT a.FoutId, a.Value
FROM ( 
     SELECT FoutId, 
            Value,
            row_number() over (partition by FoutId, Value order by FoutId, Value) as rn
     FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].extrainfoTemp ) as a
WHERE a.rn = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].ExtraInfo t2
                WHERE t2.FoutId in (
                        select t1.FoutId from [TestDatabase].[dbo].Fouten t1 where t1.FoutId = t2.FoutId))
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ExtraInfo_Fouten". The conflict occurred in database
>   "TestDatabase", table "dbo.Fouten", column 'FoutId'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

I'm assuming this is because it tries to add a row with a FoutId that isn't listed inside the [Fouten] table. Meaning something in my query is wrong but can't figure out what.

Anyone any idea on how to solve this? All the help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! My query just need some changes.

```
INSERT INTO [TestDatabase].[dbo].ExtraInfo (FoutId, Value)
SELECT a.FoutId, a.Value
FROM ( 
     SELECT FoutId, 
            Value,
            row_number() over (partition by FoutId, Value order by FoutId, Value) as rn
     FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].extrainfoTemp ) as a
WHERE a.rn = 1 and a.FoutId in (select b.FoutId from [TestDatabase].[dbo].Fouten as b where a.FoutId = b.FoutId)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM [TestDatabase].[dbo].ExtraInfo t2
                WHERE t2.FoutId = a.FoutId 
                  AND t2.Value = a.Value
                  )
```